# react native container within container

Tags: react-native

I would like to have 2 view take 50% of the space within a view.

```
export default function Home(){
    return (
        <View style={globalStyles.homepagecontainer}>
            <View style={globalStyles.practicecontainer}>
                <Text>Practice</Text>
            </View>       
            <View style={globalStyles.buycontainer}>
                <Text>Buy All</Text>
            </View>       
        </View>
        
    )
}
```

Here is the css -

```
export const globalStyles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
        padding: 50,
        backgroundColor: 'red'
    },
    homepagecontainer: {
        flex: 1,
        padding: 20,
        backgroundColor: 'green'
    },
    practicecontainer: {
        flex: 2,
        padding: 20,
        backgroundColor: 'green'
    },
    buycontainer: {
        flex: 2,
        padding: 20,
        backgroundColor: 'blue'
    },
```

Output:-

[image]

Comment: I think this should work, try restarting the dev server ‍♂️

Comment: change the practicecontainer background color and I think you should see the results of that, also, you can use flex: 1 for both of them as it doesnt really mater if you put 2 or 1 or 10 if the siblings containers are equal

Comment: thanks..yes, it worked ,just the color change caused the confusion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have already done it. : maybe you have to change colors to see it  ([snack link](https://snack.expo.io/c22nBhdRC) )

```
 container: {
        flex: 1,
        padding: 50,
        backgroundColor: 'red'
    },
    homepagecontainer: {
        flex: 1,
        padding: 20,
        backgroundColor: 'grey' // it was green
    },
    practicecontainer: {
        flex: 2,
        padding: 20,
        backgroundColor: 'green'
    },
    buycontainer: {
        flex: 2,
        padding: 20,
        backgroundColor: 'blue'
    },
```